# What is the intuition behind the formula $p \leftrightarrow (q \leftrightarrow (r \leftrightarrow ...))$?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I cooked up the formula $p \leftrightarrow (q \leftrightarrow (r \leftrightarrow ...))$ and naively thought it is a sort of "equivalence" relation. It turns out I am wrong. Suppose you have four variables in total, setting everything to false will make the formula true. However, if you have five variables, setting all variables to false will make the formula false! Having looked at a few experiments on truth tables, I nevertheless failed to find an easy intuition, but I am intrigued by the gap between the formula's simple construction and illusive patterns. I feel something is there but I couldn't grok it.

One thing I noticed include the fact that $\leftrightarrow$ is associative and commutative, so you can shift the variables around. Maybe this helps?

Comment: I might be out of my depth here, but is $\leftrightarrow$ simply 'if and only if'? And if so, what do you mean by 'the formula is true'?

Comment: @AlexanderGeldhof Yes, $\leftrightarrow$ means "iff.". I never said "the formula is true". I just said some particular assignments will make the formula true or false.

Comment: I suspect TRUE for the expression iff *even* number of propositions $p,q,\dots$ are FALSE. (Not sure yet).

Comment: $\iff$ is equivalence relations; $p \iff p$ is always true, $p \iff q $ implies $q \iff p$, and $(p \iff q) \land (q \iff r)$ implies $p \iff r$. But what you observed is not the notion of equivalence relation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let one have the finite sequence of boolean values $p_1, \cdots, p_n$. S/he takes any two among them (say, $p, q$), remove two of them, and add $p \iff q$. This decreases the length of sequence by 1, so by $n-1$ step s/he gets to the final result.

On each step, since $T \iff T$ is true, $F \iff F$ is true and $T \iff F$ is false, the parity of Falses among $p_1, \cdots, p_n$ does not changes. So, by any choice of each steps, the parity of False after final consequence is the parity of number of Falses among initial state.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, the formula is evaluated as TRUE if there is an even number of FALSES in the input variables, and FALSE if there is an odd number of FALSES among the input variables?

Comment: Correct. @AlexanderGeldhof

Comment: One can interpret it as follows; $p_1 \iff p_2 \iff \cdots \iff p_n$ is well defined no matter how the parenthesises are given.